# Aggregation problems while generating XML

Tags: xml, oracle

I'm trying to generate some XML with the various existing functions such as XMLELEMENT, XMLAGG, ...

But I can't seem to manage to generate exactly what I need to.

What I need to achieve is this :

```
<GLEntries>
    <GLEntry fac_pk="XXX">
        <FinEntryLine lfa_num="X">
            ...
        </FinEntryLine>
        ...
        <PaymentTerms>
            <PaymentTerm>XX</PaymentTerm>
            ...
        </PaymentTerms>
    </GLEntry>
    ...
</GLEntries>
```

So there can be multiple GLEntry inside GLEntries, multiple FinEntryLine inside GLEntry and multiple PaymentTerm inside PaymentTerms.

Here's what I got so far :

```
<GLEntries>
  <GLEntry entry="000049" status="E">
    <FinEntryLine number="1"/>
    <PaymentTerms>
      <PaymentTerm entry="000049"/>
    </PaymentTerms>
  </GLEntry>
  <GLEntry entry="000049" status="E">
    <FinEntryLine number="2"/>
    <PaymentTerms>
      <PaymentTerm entry="000049"/>
    </PaymentTerms>
  </GLEntry>
</GLEntries>
```

GLEntry is an invoice(facture table) and FinEntryLine are the invoice_line(ligne_de_facture table).

With this following code :

```
SELECT XMLSERIALIZE (
          CONTENT XMLELEMENT (
                        "GLEntries",
                        XMLAGG (
                           XMLELEMENT (
                              "GLEntry",
                              xmlattributes (TO_CHAR (fac_num) AS "entry",
                                             'E' AS "status"),
                              XMLCONCAT(XMLELEMENT ("FinEntryLine", xmlattributes(to_char(lfa_num) as "number")
                              )),
                              XMLELEMENT("PaymentTerms",
                                XMLELEMENT("PaymentTerm", xmlattributes(fac_num as "entry"))
                                ))))
          VERSION '1.0')
          AS xmlserialize_doc
  FROM facture,
       ligne_de_facture
 WHERE lfa_fac_fk = fac_pk
 and fac_pk = 365462;
```

My issue is that the PaymentTerms element is repeated for each FinEntryLine that is present.

I've tried multiple versions with differents uses of XMLAGG and XMLCONCAT but can't find the thing that works like I need it.

Any help and suggestion is appreciated.

Edit : tables definition :

facture :

```
fac_pk    fac_num
10        000049
20        000050
```

ligne_de_facture :

```
lfa_pk    lfa_fac_fk    lfa_num
50        10            1
60        10            2
70        20            1
```

The rest of the value in attributes are hardcoded.

Thanks

EDIT : 
With the advice of Ghassan, the PaymentTerm is present only once, but there are 2 GLEntry element with each a FinEntryLine in it, I'd need 1 GLEntry with 2 FinEntryLine.

```
 <GLEntries>
    <GLEntry entry="000049" status="E">
      <FinEntryLine number="1"/>
    </GLEntry>
    <GLEntry entry="000049" status="E">
      <FinEntryLine number="2"/>
    </GLEntry>
    <PaymentTerms>
      <PaymentTerm entry="000049"/>
    </PaymentTerms>
  </GLEntries>
```

Comment: Could you please update your question to add in the sample data in your table, so we can run your query to produce your current output.

Answer (score 0):

As you did not give any data, table desc, ... I came up with a similar query but using user_tables and user_tab_columns views. The thing is that you have the PaymentTerms element inside your XMLAgg, you need it to be outside, but this will force you to have a group by clause in your SQL. Here's the SQL I used:

```
    SELECT XMLSERIALIZE (
            CONTENT XMLELEMENT (
                            "Tables",
                            XMLAGG (
                            XMLELEMENT (
                                "Columns",
                                xmlattributes (TO_CHAR (column_id) AS "entry",
                                                'E' AS "status"),
                                XMLCONCAT(XMLELEMENT ("FinEntryLine", xmlattributes(to_char(data_length) as "number")
                                )))),
                                XMLELEMENT("PaymentTerms",
                                    XMLELEMENT("PaymentTerm", xmlattributes(t.table_name as "entry"))
                                    ))
            VERSION '1.0')
            AS xmlserialize_doc
    FROM user_tables t,
        user_tab_columns c
    WHERE t.table_name=c.table_name
    and t.table_name ='AVRO_TEST'
    group by t.table_name;
```

The output XML is:

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Tables>
    <Columns entry="1" status="E">
        <FinEntryLine number="4000"/>
    </Columns>
    <Columns entry="13" status="E">
        <FinEntryLine number="4000"/>
    </Columns>
    <Columns entry="12" status="E">
        <FinEntryLine number="4000"/>
    </Columns>
    <Columns entry="11" status="E">
        <FinEntryLine number="8"/>
    </Columns>
    <Columns entry="10" status="E">
        <FinEntryLine number="4000"/>
    </Columns>
    <Columns entry="9" status="E">
        <FinEntryLine number="4000"/>
    </Columns>
    <Columns entry="8" status="E">
        <FinEntryLine number="22"/>
    </Columns>
    <Columns entry="7" status="E">
        <FinEntryLine number="4000"/>
    </Columns>
    <Columns entry="6" status="E">
        <FinEntryLine number="4000"/>
    </Columns>
    <Columns entry="5" status="E">
        <FinEntryLine number="4000"/>
    </Columns>
    <Columns entry="4" status="E">
        <FinEntryLine number="4000"/>
    </Columns>
    <Columns entry="3" status="E">
        <FinEntryLine number="4000"/>
    </Columns>
    <Columns entry="2" status="E">
        <FinEntryLine number="22"/>
    </Columns>
    <PaymentTerms>
        <PaymentTerm entry="AVRO_TEST"/>
    </PaymentTerms>
    </Tables>
```

Comment: Thnaks, I thought I had tried that but apparently not. I updated my question with the next issue I'm facing. I can't get the 2 FinEntryLine in 1 GLEntry element.

Comment: Can you please post in the question a full sample of an XML document, so that we can try on it instead of inventing our data?